# Tmux config not retaining PWD on new-window or window split

Tags: tmux, cd-command, cwd

So I'm trying to update my `.tmux.conf file` to reflect the change for `-c` in `new-window`. I've added this to my conf and it's not working unfortunately. My new windows and panes always start in `~/`:

```
# Saner splitting.
bind v split-window -c $PWD -h
bind s split-window -c $PWD -v

# Autorename sanely.
setw -g automatic-rename on

# Better name management
bind c new-window -c $PWD
```

My expected behavior is that my new pane or window will be in the directory of which ever pane I previously was in was. So If I'm in Window 1 that is in `~/Sites/project`, my new window will also be there.

Comment: Try encapsulating `$PWD` in quotes like this: `"$PWD"`

Answer (score 5):

You're using the wrong example. ;)  Having `$PWD` as argument to `-c` means to have the newly created panes started in the directory the *`tmux` server is in*, in other words, the directory where you first started `tmux`.  The directory of the current *pane* is the one stored in the `tmux` internal variable `#{pane_current_path}`:

```
* 'default-path' has been removed.  The new-window command accepts '-c' to
  cater for this.  The previous value of "." can be replaced with: 'neww -c
  $PWD', the previous value of '' which meant current path of the pane can
  be specified as:  'neww -c "#{pane_current_path}"'
```

So the right way to do what you want would be

```
# Saner splitting.
bind v split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}" -h
bind s split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}" -v

# Autorename sanely.
setw -g automatic-rename on

# Better name management
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

**Note:** This will *not* work if there's someone else's shell running in your current pane (I fell over this, so I explicitly tell you):  If you've a running `sudo` or `su` session, you're new pane will end up with a working directory of `/`.  This is quite simply to explain: your `tmux` cannot obtain the current working directory of the running process, since it hasn't the appropriate privileges to do so for security reasons (you cannot read vital state of a foreign user's process).